# how to centralize layout in center and top with two buttons

Tags: android, layout

I have a layout it has a frame layout which will show image and on that image I want to show two buttons on the top of screen. On the background of these two screen there is a transparent horizontal bar which I am setting as the background of the Relative or LinearLayout.

and then I want to put two buttons over it which has a good distance between them and I want the background of relative layout just get end after the right/left edge of buttons. In other case I do not want the bar to fill the whole width. What I want here , I am posting here in the image. check out the [link](http://postimg.org/image/xs7s3qe0h/) for better understanding that what I want.  I have done this but this is not so much flexible as on some devices It looks odd.

and If I use the weight and weight some then the width of button images stretch which looks very odd as my images stretch in width. I have images in square form.

Here is what I am trying :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_image"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_gallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_gallery"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_share"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_share" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just put your two buttons in `horizontal` `LinearLayout` and set gravity `top` for layout.

Comment: Have you implemented it? Show me file.

Comment: I cnt attach image :(

Comment: can you please send me the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="60dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it is taking full width of screen which is not required @piyus gupta

Comment: Have you seen the picture I shared in link

Comment: Check the answer again.

Comment: its slightly off from both side ,,,,, as you set 5 dp

Comment: cant we set it to wrap content ?

Comment: Yes. You can. Is this not useful?

Comment: it is after setting the wrap content

Comment: Okay. So you need to remove margin left and right from that and width will be `wrap_content` and also set `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Answer (score 2):

set `layout_width` to `match_parent`.
and add `android:gravity ="center"` to both button.

Answer (score 0):

try this to make a better alignment as per ur reference.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout 

     android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_gallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
   </RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 

     android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_share"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is not letting the space between both button I want an appropriate space between them and also it is stretching the image size of button which I also do not want

Comment: the background of bar is taking the whole width Which I do not wan t

Comment: still the background (transparent_image ) is taking the whole  of width

Comment: @stacyqueen no i have set margins for the purpose it'll avoid that try with android:color/transparent inspite of drawable image to check the change

Comment: why it is divided into two parts bro

Comment: @stacyqueen to make the image inside button to get too much extended to width this will keep them in a distance and will wrap its width based on it's containg image.did you try it?